# Writing test code

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

Need to write test code for the following Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class whitespace{

    transient public String AccountID{get;set;}
    transient public String PAccountID{get;set;}
    transient public List<Account>TIPlist{get;set;}
    transient public String t{get;set;}
    transient Map<String,List<Installed_Products__c>> IPList{get;set;}
    transient public String Account_Name {get;set;}
    transient public list<Installed_Products__c> P{get;set;}


    public whitespace(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        }
        public Map<String,List<String>> IPListM{
            get{
                //Selects Account ID and Parent ID
                AccountID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
                PAccountID = [select ParentId from Account where ID = :AccountID].ParentId;

                //Queries Account info based on criteria
                if (PAccountID == null){
                    TIPList = [select Name,(select Account__c,Product_Family__c from Product_Releases_del__r ORDER BY Product_Family__c ASC) from Account a where ParentID =: AccountID];
                }
                else {
                    TIPList = [select Name,(select  Account__c,Product_Family__c from Product_Releases_del__r ORDER BY Product_Family__c ASC) from Account a  where ParentID =: PAccountID];   
                }
                //Declares Map and List
                Map<String,List<String>> IPList = new Map<String,List<String>>();

                for(integer j = 0; j < TIPList.size(); j++){ 
                    List <String> P = new List<String>{};
                    //sets temporary variable t, Account Name as String and clears the product list
                    P.clear();
                    t = '';
                    Account_Name = TIPList[j].Name;



                    for(Integer i = (TIPList[j].Product_Releases_del__r.size()-1) ; i >= 0; i--){
                        system.debug(TIPList[j]);
                        Installed_Products__c x = TIPList[j].Product_Releases_del__r[i];

                        if(t == x.Product_Family__c){
                            }
                        else{
                            system.debug(TIPList[j].Product_Releases_del__r[i].Product_Family__c);
                            system.debug(TIPList[j]);
                            P.add(TIPList[j].Product_Releases_del__r[i].Product_Family__c);
                            t = x.Product_Family__c;
                                }
                        }




                    system.debug(P);
                    system.debug(Account_Name);
                    IPList.put(Account_Name, P);
                    system.debug(IPlist);
                    }  
                return IPList;
                }



            set;
    }
}
```

I am a novice apex programmer and I am having trouble wrapping my head around the concept of test code. Can someone a) help with this class b) explain what the main process for writing tests is?

Thanks

Comment: Lets not down vote / close this until we see where this goes. I think the OP is just trying to understand and not trying to get code written (I could be wrong). Sometimes getting an answer here vs just reading the docs could be the tipping point the OP needs.

Comment: @Eric where should I be checking whether the ParentId is null. I have if/else statements, but I am assuming you are saying that they come after the initial query. Should I be using try/except? What would you suggest?

Comment: You should be checking if the `AccountID` is null as your query for parent is depending on this and you will get a dereference null error as you are expecting one results and dereferencing to the ParentID value

Comment: @Eric sorry for my ignorance, but how do I do that?

Comment: this is such a basic everyday thing to do that if you are unable to do this you really should be going to developer.salesforce.com and educate yourself on the basic fundementals....Simply giving you the code will not help you in the long run.....Maybe time to close this question now....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to wrap your head around it......

You have to get your mindset in a mode of:

1. Step by step
2. What happens in the UI
3. Do that in the test code
4. Check that the results were as you expected..

This is a starting point. From here you can add additional methods to test specific logic and results, functionality, etc. If you had a method that does something very specific, add a test method to ensure that is working. What you do not want is one long test method....rather you want a test class with a bunch of targeted test methods that assert for results and cover all your business logic (thus covering the code).

**Notice in the test, one method will fail because you have a problem with your code posted above - fix the code above and the test will pass**

```
     @isTest

    private class exampleTestClass{

     //You will want to break the test methods up into functional chncks testing the core components of your class
     //For example, if you have a requirement that the Account ID must be passed in, have a method to test it being there and a method to test it not

     private static testMethod void noAccountID(){
        //Instantiate the controller
        whitespace con = New whitespace(New apexPages.standardController(New Account()));
        //Now here you should assert that there was an error returned
        //BUT, you class will fail because you are not checking in your code that the ID parameter was null
        //thus your query for PAAccountID will throw an error.
     }

     private static testMethod void basicTest(){ //I usually do one of these to walk through the simplest VF example
        //broken out for simplicity            
        Account parentAccount = New Account(name='Test Parent'); //Create Parent Account
        insert parentAccount
        Account a = New Account(name = 'Test Account', ParentID = parentAccount.id); //Create a test account
        insert a;

        //YOU Build the records required for the TP List

        //Instantiate the controller
        whitespace con = New whitespace(New apexPages.standardController(a));

        //Now you need to assert that the correct values are populated
        system.assertEquals(false,con.IPList.isEmpty()); //Better if you check for specific values


     }


}
```

**NOTE** In is not sufficient from a business perspective to test only positive cases (where outcome is expected), you should also be testing (with methods) that the negative is handled - Like what if Product_Releases_del__r found no records, what should the results be, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Eric's answer, I'd also put forward that during a 'Best Practice' session at Salesforce World Tour London. Avoid using 'seealldata="true"' and when working with users or records, don't use hard-coded ID's, for example.

If you wanted to test what happens when a particular profile tries to perform a task on an application, create a test one as below:

```
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Recruitment Consultant'];
User u = new User(
  Alias = 'testu',
  Email = 'test@example.com',
  EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
  LastName = 'Test',
  LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
  LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
  TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
  ProfileId = p.Id,
  UserName='test@example.com'
);

System.runAs(u) {
  // The test
}
```

Similarly, creating records in the test class for use by the test class is also much better practice.

```
my_object__c obj = new my_object__c (
  Name = 'Test Project',
  Objectives__c = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
);

insert obj;
```

The reason for doing this is to keep things as dynamic as possible. If a user is deactivated, or if a record is deleted, your test classes will fail.

I appreciate this isn't quite as good an answer as Eric's, more as an add-on, but as someone who couldn't see the point in test classes up until very recently I figured I'd share this little 'factoid'.

**Edit**
Eric displayed this in his answer I know, I wanted to elaborate slightly on that because it's something I was guilty of and given it was brought up at SWT:L I'm guessing I wouldn't be the first nor the last.

Comment: Good additions and clarifications. What was your ahaaa moment when it finally clicked?

Comment: When a user was deactivated (they just left the business) and I had to rewrite almost every single test class. That was a fun week! In my defense it was inherited bad practice as my background is in PHP, not Apex or similar (e.g. Java), from another developer as I was (and still am!) learning. No excuse not to do my research though!